# Parse parameters in url after /

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-parameters

I have my site: www.mysite.com/

And I want to get the last part of the url to enter profile: www.mysite.com/profile/NAME

How i can get NAME ( in PHP ), and where the code is run, because it would take NAME as a folder.

Comment: Look into `parse_url()`

Comment: You need `.htaccess` to make the request get to the PHP script in the first place.

Comment: The term you need to Google is `mod rewrite`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That's exactly what I do not know. You Might pass me a link to guide me?

Comment: BTW, anybody who would have removed the PHP tag: I disagree with removing PHP from the tags in that, were PHP to utilize some form of URL page routing (not rewriting) that ASP.NET could use, the PHP tag would still be applicable.  I do knot know that there exists such a technique in PHP; I'm just asking people to remember there's more than one way to do things, and furthermore if url rewriting is the way to do it, beginners using PHP should know.  I'm adding back the PHP tag.

Comment: (This question is likely a duplicate anyway...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what is in my .htaccess file and it works in prod

It takes a name such as www.website.com/userprofile and puts in a link named www.website.com/webpage.php?u=userprofile

```
# PROFILER
RewriteEngine On
# force non-www domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://website.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w_|-]+)$ webpage.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w_|-]+)\/$ webpage.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit unclear.  To access parts of the url for operations:

Check out the super global $_SERVER[].  It has various options that may be useful to you.  Specifically:

> 'PHP_SELF' The filename of the currently executing script, relative to
>   the document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at
>   the address www.example.com/foo/bar.php would be /foo/bar.php. The
>   **FILE** constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file. If PHP is running as a command-line processor
>   this variable contains the script name since PHP 4.3.0. Previously it
>   was not available.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

As it says, the **FILE** constant may be of help, or you could use:

```
explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

which will give a hash of:

```
{0 => "foo", 1 => "bar.php"}
```

Be careful here though.  If you allow arbitrary queries and use those queries to access files on your server, you could be introducing serious security issues.

If instead, you mean you want the url to display as you've written:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html